# Uncaught TypeError: marked is not a function at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, markdown

I tried to make this simple notes app, just for learning javascript. Then I got error when I tried to hit the "edit" button on this program. It was saying that marked is not a function.

My code is here:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Notes App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/4.2.12/marked.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>
<body>
        
<div class="notes">
    <div class="tools">
        <button class="edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        <button class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="main hidden">
        
    </div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ibarra+Real+Nova&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #7BDAF3;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
}

.notes {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 400;
    height: 400;
    margin: 20px;
}

.notes .tools {
    background-color: #9ec862;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.notes .tools button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.notes .main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.notes textarea {
    outline: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.notes .hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const notesEl = document.querySelector('.notes');
const editBtn = document.querySelector('.edit');
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete');

const main = notesEl.querySelector('.main');
const textArea = notesEl.querySelector('textarea');

editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    main.classList.toggle('hidden');
    textArea.classList.toggle('hidden');
});

textArea.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    main.innerHTML = marked(value);
});
```

It supposed to show the mark when I hit the edit button. But, even without giving any input of markdown, the result is nothing. And it showed an error on the console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. So that there is a bug in this version of mark, then I change the marked version to 3.0.7. And its all works fine, cause its fixed in this version.

So change the way you import it in html code:
from:
**`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/4.2.12/marked.min.js`**
to:
**`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@3.0.7/marked.min.js`**

Comment: The correct URL is:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@4.3.0/lib/marked.umd.min.js

See: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/marked

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL for the NPM is:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@4.3.0/lib/marked.umd.min.js

See: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/marked

You then have to access it as below prefixing with **marked.**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Marked in the browser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
      marked.parse('# Marked in the browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```